# Visual CSV Reader what doesn't keep the file "open"

Tags: excel, csv, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to view CSV files as you would in Excel (nice clear layout) the only issue with Excel is that it doesn't notify you of updates nor does it close the file once it's "open" unlike Notepad++ which allows you to see when the file is updated and it also allows you to have the file open then manipluate it in lets say python...

The only problem with Notepad++ is it's impossible to read a CSV easily..

#### Notepad++

- **Pros**

  - *"This file has been modified by another program, Would you like to reload it?"*
  - Closes the file once the data is loaded visually.
  - Can compare against other files easily.
- **Cons**

  - No clear visual viewer.

#### Excel

- **Pros**

  - Clear visual viewer.
- **Cons**

  - Doesn't close the file once the data is loaded visually.
  - Doesn't alert you when the file has been modified by another program (you can't modify it if it's open in Excel)
  - Can't compare to another file easily.

Anyone know of a program to help me?

#### Before

```
data,data,datalongdatadatalongdata,datalongdata,datalongdata,data,data,data,datalongdata,data,data,data,data,datalongdata,datalongdata,data
data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,datalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdata,data
data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data'data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,datalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdata,data,data
```

#### After (Look at line 5 for `data'data`)

```
data,data,datalongdatadatalongdata,datalongdata,datalongdata,data,data,data,datalongdata,data,data,data,data,datalongdata,datalongdata                                                ,data
data,data,data                    ,data        ,data        ,data,data,data,data        ,data,data,data,data,data        ,data                                                        ,data
data,data,data                    ,data        ,data        ,data,data,data,data        ,data,data,data,data,data        ,data                                                        ,data
data,data,data                    ,data        ,data        ,data,data,data,data        ,data,data,data,data,data        ,datalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdata,data
data,data,data                    ,data        ,data        ,data,data,data,data'data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data                    ,data        ,data        ,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data                    ,data        ,data        ,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data                    ,data        ,data        ,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,datalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdata,data,data
```

Comment: @Whoever wants to close this thread, instead of just clicking close try and explain your reasoning as to why you feel this post should be closed...

Comment: It *might* have something to do with how your question seems to be comparing software products as well as how you're asking for suggestions of a program to help you accomplish what you're trying to do. But since it's only one person who has voted to close so far, it's probably not that big of a deal. I for one think your question is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm back with a new answer :) After you found that bug in `TextFX`, I decided to create something better using the `Python Script` plugin.

### Examples

It will convert the following example:

```
heeey,this,is,a,testtttttttttt
34,3
123,123,123,123,123
```

To:

```
+ ----------------------------------------- +
| heeey | this | is  | a   | testtttttttttt |
| 34    | 3    |     |     |                |
| 123   | 123  | 123 | 123 | 123            |
+ ----------------------------------------- +
```

And the following:

```
title1,title2,title3,title4,title5,title6,title7,title8,title9
datalongdata,datalongdata,data,data,data,datalongdata,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data,data,data,datalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdata,data
data,data'data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
```

To:

```
+ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ +
| title1       | title2       | title3 | title4 | title5 | title6       | title7 | title8                                                       | title9 |
+ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ +
| datalongdata | datalongdata | data   | data   | data   | datalongdata | data   | data                                                         | data   |
| data         | data         | data   | data   | data   | data         | data   | datalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdatadatalongdata | data   |
| data         | data'data    | data   | data   | data   | data         | data   | data                                                         | data   |
+ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ +
```

### Installation

1. Install `Python Script` plugin, from `Plugin Manager` or from the [official website](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).
2. When installed, go to `Plugins > Python Script > New Script`. Choose a filename for your new file (eg `pretty_csv.py`) and copy the code that follows.
3. Open your csv file and then run `Plugins > Python Script > Scripts > pretty_csv.py`. this will open a new tab with your table.

*Please note that in the first few lines of the script you can alter some parameters. I hope that the variables names are self-explanatory! I guess the most important ones are the boolean ones, `border` and `header`*.

```py
#define parameters
delimiter=","
new_delimiter=" | "
border=True
border_vertical_left="| "
border_vertical_right=" |"
border_horizontal="-"
border_corner_tl="+ "
border_corner_tr=" +"
border_corner_bl="+ "
border_corner_br=" +"
header=True
border_header_separator="-"
border_header_left="+ "
border_header_right=" +"
newline="\n"

#load csv
content=editor.getText()
content=content.rstrip(newline)
rows=content.split(newline)

#find the max number of columns (so having rows with different number of columns is no problem)
max_columns=max([row.count(delimiter) for row in rows])
if max_columns>0:
    max_columns=max_columns+1

    #find the max width of each column
    column_max_width=[0]*max_columns
    for row in rows:
        for index,column in enumerate(row.split(delimiter)):
            width=len(column)
            if width>column_max_width[index]:
                column_max_width[index]=width
    total_length=sum(column_max_width)+len(new_delimiter)*(max_columns-1)

    #create new document
    notepad.new()

    #apply the changes
    left=border_vertical_left if border is True else ""
    right=border_vertical_right if border is True else ""
    left_header=border_header_left if border is True else ""
    right_header=border_header_right if border is True else ""
    for row_number,row in enumerate(rows):
        columns=row.split(delimiter)
        max_index=len(columns)-1
        for index in range(max_columns):
            if index>max_index:
                columns.append(' ' * column_max_width[index])
            else:
                diff=column_max_width[index]-len(columns[index])
                columns[index]=columns[index] + ' ' * diff

        if row_number==0 and border is True: #draw top border
            editor.addText(border_corner_tl + border_horizontal * total_length + border_corner_tr + newline)
        editor.addText(left + new_delimiter.join(columns) + right + newline) #print the new row
        if row_number==0 and header is True: #draw header's separator
            editor.addText(left_header + border_header_separator * total_length + right_header + newline)
        if row_number==len(rows)-1 and border is True: #draw bottom border
            editor.addText(border_corner_bl + border_horizontal * total_length + border_corner_br)
else:
    console.clear()
    console.show()
    console.writeError("No \"%s\" delimiter found!" % delimiter)
```

If you find any bugs or have any suggestions please let me know!

Comment: Oh wow, that's beautiful :O, should be some sort of permanent feature to the csv module :P lol

Comment: Possible to make it callable: `import prettycsv` and then `prettycsv("mycsvfile.csv")` which would save it as: `prettycsv_mycsvfile.csv` ?

Comment: This wouldn't work, because the above script make use of the `editor`, `notepad` and `console` special objects for manipulating Notepad++. I guess you want a pure Python library, right? If so, I might do it for you and share a link in the next few days.

Comment: @Hyflex here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20025235/2140859 Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 5):

You will never achieve the great visual experience of Excel in Notepad++!

The only "solution" I know of, lie inside the TextFX plugin.

Select all your text, and then go to `TextFX > TextFX Edit > Line up multiple lines by (,)`. This will convert the following example:

```
heeey,this,is,a,testtttttttttt
34,3,2234,3,5
123,123,123,123,123
```

To:

```
heeey,this,is  ,a  ,testtttttttttt
34   ,3   ,2234,3  ,5
123  ,123 ,123 ,123,123
```

PS. You might want to check [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/). Never had to use it so I don't know if it has all the features you need, but from the screenshot it looks good :)

Comment: The textfx version is way better than nothing, although it seems to go funny now and again (500 rows of data, the first 100 worked, then there are 20-30 rows broken (midway though...) then it continues, then breaks lol

Comment: Wow, looks bad! Can you paste this particular portion of text so I can check it too?

Comment: That's the problem, that's why I posted as an image as it as confidential student data in the csv file which for legal reasons I can't post :(

Comment: It has something to do with the character: `'` see my original post, I've added some data so you can cause the same bug.

Comment: Indeed. This is a bug! Unfortunately TextFX is no longer maintained so this can't be fixed. With 2 extra steps you can still use it. Replace (CTRL+H) all `'` instances with `|||`, run the TextFX command, and convert the `|||` back!

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing exactly what you just mentioned with the replace :P works well enough much better than me having to open excel, close... etc -_-