# delete rows by date and add file name column for multiple csv

Tags: python, date, csv, append

I have multiple "," delimited csv files with recorded water pipe pressure sensor data, already sorted by date older-newer. For all original files, the first column always contains dates formated as YYYYMMDD. I have looked at similar discussion threads but couldn't find what I need.

1. Python script to add a new column to every csv file in the directory, where each row of the new column titled as "Pipe" would have a file name, omitting file extension string.
2. Have the option of specifying a cut off date as YYYYMMDD in order to delete rows in the orginal input file. For example, if some file has dates 20140101 to 20140630, I would like cut out rows of data if their date is < 20140401.
3. Have the option of either to overwrite the original files after having made these modifications or save each file to a different directory, with file names same as the originals.

Input: PipeRed.csv; Headers: Date,Pressure1,Pressure2,Temperature1,Temperature2 etc,

Output: PipeRed.csv; Headers:  Pipe,Date,Pressure1,Pressure2,Temperature1, Temperature2,etc,

I have found some code and modified it a little, but it doesn't delete rows like was described above and adds the file name column last rather than 1st.

```
import csv
import sys
import glob
import re

for filename in glob.glob(sys.argv[1]):
#def process_file(filename):
    # Read the contents of the file into a list of lines.
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    contents = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    # Use a CSV reader to parse the contents.
    reader = csv.reader(contents)

    # Open the output and create a CSV writer for it.
    f = open(filename, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # Process the header.
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow( ('Date','Pressure1','Pressure2','Pressure3','Pressure4','Pipe') )
    header = reader.next()
    header.append(filename.replace('.csv',""))
    writer.writerow(header)

    # Process each row of the body.
    for row in reader:
        row.append(filename.replace('.csv',""))
        writer.writerow(row)

    # Close the file and we're done.
    f.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: You ask two questions: (1) how to read, insert data and save in a CSV file; (2) how to save data in a file with the same or different name.  You might want to let us know if you are looking for a solution where the read, insert, write steps are separable.  That is, are you interested in reading to an array first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should be very close to what you want. I've tested it in both Python 2.7.9 and 3.4.2. The initial version I posted had some problems because — as I mention then — it was untested. I'm not sure if you're using Python 2 or 3, but this worked properly in either one.

Another change from the previous version is that the optional keyword date argument's name had been changed from `cutoff_date` to `start_date` to better reflect what it is. A [cutoff date](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cut-off-date) usually means the last date on which it is possible to do something—the opposite of the way you used it in your question. Also note that any date provided should a string, i.e. `start_date='20140401'`, not as an integer.

One enhancement is that it will now create the output directory if one is specified but doesn't already exist.

```
import csv
import os
import sys

def open_csv(filename, mode='r'):
    """ Open a csv file in proper mode depending on Python verion. """
    return (open(filename, mode=mode+'b') if sys.version_info[0] == 2 else
            open(filename, mode=mode, newline=''))

def process_file(filename, start_date=None, new_dir=None):
    # Read the entire contents of the file into memory skipping rows before
    # any start_date given (assuming row[0] is a date column).
    with open_csv(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader)  # Save first row.
        contents = [row for row in reader if start_date and row[0] >= start_date
                                                or not start_date]

    # Create different output file path if new_dir was specified.
    basename = os.path.basename(filename)  # Remove dir name from filename.
    output_filename = os.path.join(new_dir, basename) if new_dir else filename
    if new_dir and not os.path.isdir(new_dir):  # Create directory if necessary.
        os.makedirs(new_dir)

    # Open the output file and create a CSV writer for it.
    with open_csv(output_filename, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        # Add name of new column to header.
        header = ['Pipe'] + header  # Prepend new column name.
        writer.writerow(header)

        # Data for new column is the base filename without extension.
        new_column = [os.path.splitext( os.path.split(basename)[1] )[0]]

        # Process each row of the body by prepending data for new column to it.
        writer.writerows((new_column+row for row in contents))
```

Comment: Great script! Unfortunately, when I try to execute it in Windows command promt  processfile.py *.csv in same directory where csv files are located, I get an error "Warning: 'with' will become reserved keyword in Python 2.6 File "C:\input\processfile.py", line 8 Syntax Error: invalid syntax

Comment: If you can't update to a modern version of Python, you can easily change the `with open(filename, 'rb') as f:` line to `f = open(filename, 'rb')` and un-indent the indented lines under it by one level. Then following those, add an `f.close()` to manually close the file. Next repeat the same conversion process on other `with` block.

Comment: I just checked and [`with` statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) were added in Python 2.5, so something else must be the cause of the problem — and I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Yes, have had Python 3.1 installed on the system. I un-indented the lines but it still doesn't execute. This is how parts of your code look after having manually modified the 'with' blocks 
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)  # Save separately.
    contents = [row for row in reader if cutoff_date and row[0] >=  cutoff_date]
    f.close()

    f = open(output_filename, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
  
    new_column = [os.path.split(basename)[0]]

    writer.writerows((new_column+row for row in contents))
    f.close()

Comment: Very strange indeed. The code doesn't even work in its original form with Python 3.4 on Windows XP in VM console. But can't find what's wrong with it...

Comment: Some machines have both (2.7.9 & 3.4.2) versions installed while others just one. I saved your code as a processfiles.py and then tried executing it in windows xp command terminal C:\pressure\processfiles.py *.csv - but nothing happens. Did a variation of the command 'python processfiles.py *.csv' as I normally do with other .py scripts. Did you use the Py console to run the code?

Comment: Just like in my original answer, the updated version consists only of function definitions, which will need to be called and passed suitable arguments to do anything. To test it I wrote a small driver script that called the `process_file()` function with various argument combinations. If you want to run it from the os command-prompt you'll need to write something that passes the command-line arguments to the function. Especially since now there's potentially two extra arguments beside the file name, namely a date and a new directory. Capiche?

Comment: Thank you very much! Significant improvement in processing time..over 15x