# How do i add headers to my list (csv)

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python and i have decided to use csv and I do not know how to add headers to each of my columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def Option_B():
import csv
print("Estimate Number","Date","Customer_ID","Final_Total","Status","Amount_Paid")
with open("paintingJobs.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for columns in reader: 
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print (columns)
```

This is the outcome i would want

```
 title 1   title 2       3       4      5    6
['E5345', '22/09/2015', 'C106', '815', 'A', '400']
['E5348', '23/09/2015', 'C109', '370', 'A', '200']
['E5349', '25/09/2015', 'C110', '480', 'A', '250']
['E5353', '28/09/2015', 'C114', '272', 'A', '200']
['E5355', '29/09/2015', 'C116', '530', 'A', '450']
['E5363', '01/10/2015', 'C124', '930', 'A', '500']
['E5364', '02/10/2015', 'C125', '915', 'A', '800']
['E5367', '03/10/2015', 'C128', '427', 'A', '350']
['E5373', '10/10/2015', 'C134', '1023', 'A', '550']
```

Comment: What you're wanting to do isn't clear. Please show the desired output.

Comment: Is there anyway which i can add headers to each of the columns

Comment: I'm sure there is. Where do you want them to be placed in your output? Please add all additional information _to your question_.

Comment: Above each the different sections of string so above e5345 then 22/09/2015 etc

Comment: Above each row or once above all of them? You can print a list of column headers by using `print(['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', ...etc]`) anytime you want.

Comment: In this case i want it to be above the whole list once so a title would appear once above e5345 and 22/09/2015 etc

Comment: In that case I've already answered your question.

Comment: The problem with this is when i run it the titles overlap

Comment: Please _edit your question_ and put in your modified code and desired output.

Comment: Ok so what should i do to make sure the titles do not overlap

Comment: I'm working on it. It's a little more involved than I thought because (apparently) you want the titles to line up over each column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pretty Print a CSV file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025235/how-to-pretty-print-a-csv-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want requires processing all the rows of the csv file twice in order to determine the maximum width of items in each column in order to justify the column headers properly. So, in the code below, the file is read two times. It would be faster, of course, to read the entire file into memory, if it's not too big because disk I/O is much slower than accessing data already held in memory.

```
import csv

FILE_NAME = "paintingJobs.txt"
COL_HEADERS = ['title 1', 'title 2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
NUM_COLS = len(COL_HEADERS)

# read file once to determine maximum width of data in columns
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # determine the maximum width of the data in each column
    max_col_widths = [len(col_header) for col_header in COL_HEADERS]
    for columns in reader:
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            for i, col in enumerate(columns):
                    max_col_widths[i] = max(max_col_widths[i], len(repr(col)))
    # add 1 to each for commas
    max_col_widths = [col_width+1 for col_width in max_col_widths]

# read file second time to display its contents with the headers
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # display justified column headers
    print(' ' + ' '.join(col_header.ljust(max_col_widths[i])
                            for i, col_header in enumerate(COL_HEADERS)))
    # display column data
    for columns in reader:
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print(columns)
```

Output:

```
 title 1  title 2       3       4       5    6
['E5345', '22/09/2015', 'C106', '815', 'A', '400']
['E5348', '23/09/2015', 'C109', '370', 'A', '200']
['E5349', '25/09/2015', 'C110', '480', 'A', '250']
['E5353', '28/09/2015', 'C114', '272', 'A', '200']
['E5355', '29/09/2015', 'C116', '530', 'A', '450']
['E5363', '01/10/2015', 'C124', '930', 'A', '500']
['E5364', '02/10/2015', 'C125', '915', 'A', '800']
['E5367', '03/10/2015', 'C128', '427', 'A', '350']
['E5373', '10/10/2015', 'C134', '1023', 'A', '550']
```

**Note**: For portability, reading (and writing) csv files with the `csv` module should be in binary mode for operating systems that differentiate between that and a "text" mode like Windows does. To open a file for reading in binary mode in Python 2, use `open('filename', 'rb')`, and in Python 3 use `open('filename', 'r', newline='')`. Opening files for writing is done by replacing the `r` with `w`.

Also note the use of `len(repr(col))` when computing the width of each item in a column. This is because `columns` is a list and `print(columns)` displays the *representation* of each item in the list as opposed to just its value (i.e. for a string, it's the difference between getting `'E5345'` and `E5345`).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Much appreciated.