# How to split a csv file row to columns in python?

Tags: python

Sorry, I am new to python. I have a csv file that gets data from google trends and writes to that file. However the output is all written to a same column. I want the date on column A and Bitcoin on column B and Cyptocurrency on column C and so on. I am really struggling with the simple task. Can any one help please? Thanks.

Below is the sample of the csv file.

```
"date   Bitcoin Cryptocurrency  Crypto  isPartial" 
"2013-10-27 5   0   0   False"
"2013-11-03 5   0   0   False"
"2013-11-10 5   0   0   False"
"2013-11-17 12  0   0   False"
"2013-11-24 14  0   0   False"
"2013-12-01 13  0   0   False"
```

This is my code to generate the file

```
#login
pytrend = TrendReq(google_username,google_password)
pytrend = TrendReq()

#Payload
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['Bitcoin','Cryptocurrency','Crypto'])

#interest over time
interest_over_time_df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
df = pd.DataFrame(interest_over_time_df)
file_name = "/Users/username/Desktop/Bitcoin.csv"
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far.  is it tabs or spaces?

Comment: Is there something you know beforehand, like that columns there are or how many records there are?

Comment: Can you supply your current code that prints this out so that I may help you? Also for some help trying to formar your output look into [Python Pretty Table](https://pypi.org/project/PrettyTable/)

Comment: Its tabs. There are 253 rows. But the data will keep on changing. So the number of rows will not be definite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go. You will need pandas to load into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe= pd.read_csv('Bitcoin.csv',delimiter=r"\s+")
dataframe
```

[image]

Comment: thanks mate. You are a life saver. This is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at the CSV documentation for python, this should give you all the [info and examples you need](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html)

Then I understand you want to write your rows as CSV separated by tabs so something like this should work for you:

```
# First you create a csv.Writer
spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
# You write a row as a list into the csv.writer
spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able find a few idea from other posts. Option 1 is simply just using formatting to make it look nice while Option 2 utilizes PrettyTable to give nice and formatted answer. You can find Pretty Table documenation [here](https://pypi.org/project/PrettyTable/)

**Option 1** comes this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025235/how-to-pretty-print-a-csv-file-in-python). All you would have to do is play around with the numbers so that the spacing is looks good enough to make you happy and of course change the file name to match your csv file.

## Option 1

You could use format to left justify your output. For example,

```
f = open("contactlist.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<20} {:<25}'.format(*row))
```

**Output:**

```
Name             Phone            Company              Email                    
Elon Musk        454-6723         SpaceX               emusk@spacex.com         
Larry Page       853-0653         Google               lpage@gmail.com          
Tim Cook         133-0419         Apple                tcook@apple.com          
Steve Ballmer    456-7893         Developers!          sballmer@bluescreen.com
```

You can read more about format here. The `<` symbol left-aligns the text, and the number specifies the width of the string. Each `{}` can include a positional argument before the colon `:` - if they are omitted, the strings will appear in the order of the arguments in the unpacked list row.

## Option 2

**Option 2** I was able to find this information from here, [Python Pretty Table](http://zetcode.com/python/prettytable/)

This page give you multitude of ways for solving this problem. Inlcuding a very simple of way by using the `from_csv()` function that can be imported from PrettyTable by using `from prettytable import from_csv`. Look at the example below for better insight.

Example:
Data.csv

```
"City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"
"Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5
"Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4
"Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7
"Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5
"Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8
"Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9
"Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4
```

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from prettytable import from_csv
    
with open("data.csv", "r") as fp: 
    x = from_csv(fp)
    
print(x)
```

Output will look something like the following:

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
|  Adelaide | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
|  Brisbane | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
|   Darwin  | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
|   Hobart  | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
|   Sydney  | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
|   Perth   | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

Please let me know if this was beneficial by leaving a comment or casting a vote, thank you!