# Series of Replaces in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have about 200 regular expression searches and it's a pain to copy and paste them one by one. Is there an addon/plugin for Notepad++ that would automatically fill in the Search For and Replace fields or something of the sorts? If not is there a better way to do it? I would be dealing with the same file and using all of the same searches and probably add more searches as time goes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ is not suited for this kind of batch work. I'd recommend you to find another tool, or try a scripting language.

If you really want to use Notepad++ for this task, I think you have only 2 options:

- **Macros**. You can record a macro while you are applying your regular expressions one-by-one in the Replace dialog. Save it, and then you can Play the Macro whenever and wherever you want. Caveat: you can't easily add new regular expressions. Actually it's possible by modifying manually the `shortcuts.xml` that you will find in your `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\` folder. This is where the recorded Macros are stored after you restart Notepad++. You can cut a new Macro with your new regular expressions and paste it in your older Macro. But it's a dirty job, I'll suggest you to move on to the next option.
- [**Python Script plugin**](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/). You can write a Python script applying all your regular expressions. Once the script created, it will be very easy to add new regular expressions. Check a previous post of mine on [how to install and use the plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907946/visual-csv-reader-what-doesnt-keep-the-file-open/19964917#19964917) and then edit the following script (let's name it `batch_regex.py`) accordingly:

  ```py
  editor.pyreplace(r"foo", r"bar") #this is a Python regular expression
  editor.pyreplace(r"baz", r"qux") #add here new regular expressions
  editor.pyreplace(r"test", r"yeah") #your third regular expression
  #etc...

  #if you have multiline regular expressions use pymlreplace instead (documentation: http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/scintilla.html#pymlreplace)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for responding. That sounds like what Im wanting to do. I will try it out but I know nothing of python but from what you describe I shouldnt have any problems. I assume the r"foo" (mine will be regexp) is what it will search for and r"bar" (mine will be regular text) is what it will replace it with. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. Give it a try and if you have any trouble let me know.

Comment: I got it setup and so far it works GREAT. Dont know if Ill have any problems later but so far so good. I did notice that I dont need the r"bar" to insert regular text, instead deleted the r and have "bar", unless you see a problem there.

Comment: The `r""` notation is not necessary, so proceed with no fear! But in some regular expressions it might be useful. Read more on regexes from Python's official [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: This definately was the answer I was looking for and thanks again for the info. I thought there was something to click for "solved" and I just now found where to click.

Comment: If I use the built in search and replace function with regexp, it takes 25sec to search and replace. If I use the plugin with editor.pyreplace it takes almost 9 minutes to do the same thing. If I substitute with pymlreplace it takes about 6.5 minutes but it deletes a bunch of lines and jacks up my file for some reason. The file is 13MB with 353674 lines. I can tell its working hard with %50 cpu on two cores. Do you know how to make it faster and why is pymlreplace jacking up the file?

Comment: Is it an option to share the data and the regular expressions so I can assist you? Or at least some part of it.

Comment: Basically Im taking my host file and compressing it down to use in FF along with several other changes to make a compatible format. There are tons of redundant entries as you probably know thats not needed. For one example would be 127.0.0.1 ad.doubleclick.net, I search for .*\.doubleclick\.net$ and replace with nothing, then I paste 1 127.0.0.1 doubleclick.net and go from there.

Comment: I did find something that seemed to work alot faster but am in the process of checking it for errors now. It is: editor.rereplace(r".*doubleclick\.net$", r"")

Comment: editor.rereplace is deleting a bunch of lines for no reason also. I have no idea why.

Comment: Ok I cut my python script down from 20 to 10 items and it seems like it done ok. 10 items took 8min03sec using editor.rereplace.

Comment: That's good. Make sure you use greedy quantifiers `+` and `*` wisely! (if you don't have any clue about what I'm talking about, search for this term). For even faster replacements, check if you can use `Editor.replace` to remove repetitive redundant chunks before applying regular expressions.

Comment: I have noticed that I can use editor.rereplace() for replaces that do not take alot of processing. It is much faster than editor.pyreplace(), but editor.pyreplace can handle the processing load and hasnt failed once. When editor.rereplace decides to take a dump it will delete alot of the lines and you will notice it with the line count at the bottom of Notepad++. It helps to break up your search and replace python script to multiple scripts so rereplace can handle it.