# huge data column alignment in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, multiple-columns

I have a huge text file for example like this:

```
Name:John
Age:23
Status:Single
Gender:Male
Name:Merry
Age:19
Gender:Female
Name:Alex
Age:20
Status:Single
Gender:Male
```

I want the data for every name to be in on line and aligned .I used:

```
Find:\r\nAge:
Replace: Age:
Find:\r\nStatus:
Replace: Status:
Find:\r\nGender:
Replace: Gender:
```

the output is:

```
Name:John Age:23 Status:Single Gender:Male
Name:Merry Age:19 Gender:Female
Name:Alex Age:20 Status:Single Gender:Male
```

The data are now in one line but not aligned.I want it to be like this:

```
Name:John  Age:23 Status:Single Gender:Male
Name:Merry Age:19               Gender:Female
Name:Alex  Age:20 Status:Single Gender:Male
```

Every entry (Name,Age,Status,..) in aligned column if the entry is not found the space will be reserved as in:

```
Name:Merry Age:19               Gender:Female
```

"no Status entry but still data is aligned"

Please Help..
Can i solve this by using any feature in notepad++??

Comment: Try replacing with `\t` instead. It won't make it ideal, but I don't think it's something you can do with a simple find/replace regex alone and will align most of your data.

Comment: sorry it doesn't work.the data is aligned but not in correct order the missing entry is still a problem. this just a sample. the data is very huge and I want to solve this in any way not just with find and replace

Comment: Yea, I knew that it wouldn't completely work, hence why I said 'not ideal' xD But by any way, is there any programming language you know? I would myself suggest Excel (or a spreadsheet program) just after replacing with `\t`. You'd get every name in the same column (assuming that no name is missing), and you can apply filters to sort and batch process the data where there are missing fields.

Comment: Already I am doing all this to copy this data into an excel sheet. If you try what you said you will find the "Gender" entry in the space of the "Status" when the "Status" is missing. The main problem is that the data is generated automatically and some entries is not always available

Comment: Yes, I know and that's why I also said "you can apply filters to sort and batch process the data where there are missing fields.". Basically, sort the data by Age to get all the good ages together, then move everything that doesn't have Age in the column Age one column to the right. Repeat with Status and you should be done.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. It is good but also not always i have more than 20 columns and i need to do this every day. this way it will be very hard and time consuming . i hope there is a better way so i can do it all with notepad++ and then i will use macros to record and repeat this every day

Comment: The issue seems to be more at data collection level or output if you ask me. Nowadays, people use databases for those kinds of things, and they avoid you this time lost in sorting data. Otherwise, there's not much to say...

Comment: Unfortunatally I am not good in programming. This output file is from linux machine. Can I fix this before moving it to the text editor?? If there is any linux command can help in this??

Comment: Probably, or your IT support should be able to, if you're in an organisation, since they would know the system better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can line up multiple columns using the `TextFX` plugin.

Select all your text, and then go to `TextFX` > `TextFX Edit` > `Line up multiple lines by (,)`.

Similarly you can align by any character, using the `Line up multiple lines by (Clipboard Character)` option.

Please note that in my opinion "space" should usually be avoided to be used a separator, since it can be accidentally inserted in your data and mess up your columns. Consider using a comma or semicolon instead.

---

The above solution doesn't though fulfill the *"Every entry (Name,Age,Status,..) in aligned column if the entry is not found the space will be reserved"* requirement. The only possible way using Notepad++, is with the help of the `Python Script` plugin.

And you are lucky since I have already wrote such a script, which can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19964917/2140859) :) Follow the installation guidelines, copy the script, and in your case just change the initial parameters of the script in order to remove the borders.

Edit: follows a quick adaptation of the aforementioned code. Please note that there's room for improvement, especially in the way I calculate the width of each columns, but I'm leaving that to you.

```
#define parameters
column_names=["Name","Age","Status","Gender"]
delimiter=" "
label_delimiter=":"
new_delimiter=" | "
border=True
border_vertical_left="| "
border_vertical_right=" |"
border_horizontal="-"
border_corner_tl="+ "
border_corner_tr=" +"
border_corner_bl="+ "
border_corner_br=" +"
header=True
border_header_separator="-"
border_header_left="+ "
border_header_right=" +"
newline="\n"

#load csv
content=editor.getText()
content=content.rstrip(newline)
rows=content.split(newline)

#find the max number of columns (so having rows with different number of columns is no problem)
max_columns=max([row.count(delimiter) for row in rows])
max_columns=max_columns+1
if max_columns>1 and len(column_names)==max_columns:
    #find the max width of each column
    column_max_width=[0]*max_columns
    for row in rows:
        for index,column in enumerate(row.split(delimiter)):
            width=len(column)
            if width>column_max_width[index]:
                column_max_width[index]=width
    for index,column in enumerate(column_max_width):
        column_max_width[index]=max(len(column_names[index]),column-len(column_names[index])-1)
    total_length=sum(column_max_width)+len(new_delimiter)*(max_columns-1)

    #create new document
    notepad.new()

    #apply the changes
    left=border_vertical_left if border is True else ""
    right=border_vertical_right if border is True else ""
    left_header=border_header_left if border is True else ""
    right_header=border_header_right if border is True else ""
    for row_number,row in enumerate(rows):
        temp={}
        for cell in row.split(delimiter):
            label,value=cell.split(label_delimiter)
            temp[label]=value
        columns=[]
        for index,column_name in enumerate(column_names):
            if column_name in temp:
                columns.append(temp[column_name] + ' ' * (column_max_width[index]-len(temp[column_name])))
            else:
                columns.append(' ' * column_max_width[index])

        if row_number==0 and border is True: #draw top border
            editor.addText(border_corner_tl + border_horizontal * total_length + border_corner_tr + newline)
        if row_number==0 and header is True: #draw header's separator
            column_names_printable=[]
            for index,column_name in enumerate(column_names):
                column_names_printable.append(column_name + ' ' * (column_max_width[index]-len(column_name)))
            editor.addText(left + new_delimiter.join(column_names_printable) + right + newline)
            editor.addText(left_header + border_header_separator * total_length + right_header + newline)
        editor.addText(left + new_delimiter.join(columns) + right + newline) #print the new row
        if row_number==len(rows)-1 and border is True: #draw bottom border
            editor.addText(border_corner_bl + border_horizontal * total_length + border_corner_br)
else:
    console.clear()
    console.show()
    console.writeError("No \"%s\" delimiter found or number of columns defined (%d) doesn't match the columns found (%d)!" % (delimiter,len(column_names),max_columns))
```

So, for your file:

```
Name:John Age:23 Status:Single Gender:Male
Name:Merry Age:19 Gender:Female
Name:Alex Age:20 Status:Single Gender:Male
```

will be converted to:

```
+ ----------------------------- +
| Name  | Age | Status | Gender |
+ ----------------------------- +
| John  | 23  | Single | Male   |
| Merry | 19  |        | Female |
| Alex  | 20  | Single | Male   |
+ ----------------------------- +
```

Comment: The script is working. the alignment is beautiful.but still I need solution for "Every entry (Name,Age,Status,..) in aligned column if the entry is not found the space will be reserved"

Comment: Yes I understand. I pointed you towards this solution, hoping that this will inspire you to modify the script accordingly. Give it a try, and only if you are unable to do it, let me know and I'll see if I've enough time to do it for you.

Comment: thanks I will try and I will inform you if I couldn't

Comment: could you please help in the above script

Comment: Many thanks :)@psxls the only problem is that the last right delimiter is written in new line not at the end

Comment: I edited your answer to show you my output.can you advise please

Comment: In addition it can not find the proper width for column 1 & column 11

Comment: Try to change the `newline="\n"` parameter to `newline="\r\n"` or you can go in Notepad++ and select `Edit` > `EOL Conversion` > `Windows Format`.

Comment: awesome.It is working now except the problem of improper column width for the first column and column 11

Comment: I was hoping you will be doing that! But OK, I've done it. Please check the updated code, it now calculates the width correctly. Let me know if everything is OK now (and if it is, consider accepting the answer; [read why & how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/235601)).

Comment: Thanks. every thing is OK

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex (after making sure you have a backup):

```
Find: Age:(\d+) Gender:
Replace: Age:\1               Gender:
```

*Age:(\d+) Gender* will find "Age:" followed by 1 or more digits followed by a space and followed by "Gender:".

The digits will be saved in \1, that's what the parentheses are for. You could also have more parentheses later, the contents of which would be available in \2, \3 and so on.

Also see http://markantoniou.blogspot.be/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html for more examples.

Comment: this is just an example. the text file is huge and this will not work. the alignment is still not ok